In a Jenkins pipeline, how can I disable concurrent builds in one situation, but not others?
I set my Jenkins job pipeline properties() this way
properties([
  [$class: "jenkins.model.BuildDiscarderProperty", strategy: [$class: "LogRotator", numToKeepStr: "50", artifactNumToKeepStr: "20"]],
  parameters([
    string(name: "BUILD_NODE", defaultValue: "linux", description: "Build node to use."),
    choiceParam(name: "DEBUG_LEVEL", choices: ["0", "1", "2", "3"], description: "Debugger verbosity.")
  ])
])

I want to able selectively disable concurrent builds, so as test code I tried this
List propsList = [
  [$class: "jenkins.model.BuildDiscarderProperty", strategy: [$class: "LogRotator", numToKeepStr: "50", artifactNumToKeepStr: "20"]],
  parameters([
    string(name: "BUILD_NODE", defaultValue: "linux", description: "Build node to use."),
    choiceParam(name: "DEBUG_LEVEL", choices: ["0", "1", "2", "3"], description: "Debugger verbosity.")
  ])
]
if (env.DONT_WANT_CONCURRENT_BUILDS.toBoolean()) {
  JobProperty jp = disableConcurrentBuilds()
}
properties(propsList)

But I get the following when I run the job
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '@disableConcurrentBuilds()' with class 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.UninstantiatedDescribableWithInterpolation' to class 'hudson.model.JobProperty'

What's the correct way to do this? Thanks!

This is conceptually wrong. The "disable concurrent builds" property is a property of a job. And while Jenkins allows you to set those properties dynamically during a job run, this specific property doesn't make sense there. What if your run wants to set it to true, but there is already another concurrent job running? Should Jenkins terminate that job?
Think what makes your job non-reentrant. Isolate that part with a semaphore.
